# C# Razor Viewmodel with Generic <T>?

Tags: c#, generics, razor, viewmodel

I'm trying to make a streamlined viewmodel that I can dynamically generate some html based off of.  However, I don't quite understand how (or if it's even possible) to create a viewmodel with a dynamic value.

My viewmodel:

```
public class DataGridViewModel<T>
{
    public List<T> DataList { get; set; }
    public List<HeaderValue> DataHeaders { get; set; }

    public DataGridViewModel(List<T> dataIn)
    {
        DataList = dataIn;
        SetHeaders();
    } 

    public void SetHeaders()
    {
        //Build a list of column headers based on [Display] attribute
        DataHeaders = new List<HeaderValue>();
        var t = DataList.First().GetType();
        foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties())
        {
            var gridattr = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false).FirstOrDefault(x => x is DisplayAttribute);
            var head = gridattr == null ? "" : (string) gridattr.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(gridattr);
            var visible = gridattr != null;
            DataHeaders.Add(new HeaderValue()
            {
                Header  = head,
                Visible = visible,
                Property = prop.Name
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
var docdto = DocumentService.FetchDocuments(); //Returns IQueryable<DocumentDTO>
var vm = new DataGridViewModel<DocumentDto>(docdto.ToList());
return View(vm);
```

DocumentDTO:

```
public class DocumentDto
    {
        public Int32 DocumentId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
//These could be very different, based on the table they're modeled after.
```

View:

```
@model DataGridViewModel<T>

@foreach(var header in Model.DataHeaders)
    {
        <h1>@header.Property</h1>
    }
```

The issue I'm having is, it seems the view cannot use a generic or dynamic value, and must be assigned to a base class.  The problem then is that the DTOs are all very different.

Is this possible to do with Razor?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: No sorry, it's not possible to use a generic view model like that. You will have to specialize and specify the type.

Comment: You can do something similar with a parent/child view model setup. The chosen view will always be the most derived.